Liability for third-party damages caused in self defense
"Juan" is a jeweler transporting a piece to a customer. While walking from his downtown storefront to his car, a mugger attacks him. In response, he draws a pistol and shoots the attacker. The bullet overpenetrates and detonates a propane tank, causing fire damage to a nearby building.
I can see three possibilities here:

Juan is liable for the damages, since it was his bullet.
The attacker is liable, since Juan was acting in self-defense, and (presumably) was not negligent.
Nobody is held liable.

Which is it?

https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/24201/will-i-be-liable-for-injuries-to-someone-else-resulting-from-defending-myself-in/24261
